# Variables available in grails templates

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.0.10

I am trying to edit grails scaffolding template to create individual fields in create.gsp and edit.gsp

If I add following in create.gsp

```
<%
        def d = new grails.core.GrailsDomainClass (collegeapplication.Student.class)
        d.persistentProperties.each {
            %>
    ${it}
    <%
        }
    %>
```

I get  `unable to resolve class grails.core.GrailsDomainClass`
For that matter I am not able to load any of my domain class using any of the common methods listed at [Groovy way to dynamically instantiate a class from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758398/groovy-way-to-dynamically-instantiate-a-class-from-string)
or at [Get domain class field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103173/get-domain-class-field-names)

Any ideas?

The end result I want is instead of 
`<f:all bean="parentsInfomormation"/>`
I want to the generate-all command to generate
`<f:field bean="person" property="name"/>` for each property

Comment: Why don't you try `def domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(collegeapplication.Student.class)`?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati how do I get instance of grailsApplication? I don't think it would be available anyways while running generate-all command.

Comment: you get it by default on gsp page. On templates you can use it without any issues. Try it out or If you need complete solution all together I may paste it as answer. :)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati it says no such property grailsApplication. Had already tried it.

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868845/grails-templates-scaffolding-controller?rq=1 could help you!

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I don't think it would work, looking at the date this is pre grails 3.0 where generate template was totally different

Answer (score 1):

With `scaffolding` plugin in grails 3.x, it's not possible to do what you are trying to achieve. While generating templates for domains, scaffolding plugin doesn't load any of the domain class or you can say it doesn't load the grails application.

Scaffolding plugin uses scripts generated by `create-script` to generate templates.

> In Grails 3.x it is not possible to load a Grails application within a
>   code generation script created by the `create-script` command.

For more info, read this [link](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html).

So you have two options:

1. Create your own scaffolding task using `create-command` as explained in link given above.
2. Use the scaffolding plugin and extend `FormFieldsTagLib` to define a custom behaviour for `<f:all bean=""/>` tag.