# Using grailsApplication object in Scaffolding templates

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Is it possible to access the application's configurations using the grailsApplication object in scaffolding templates?

For example:

If I have this in my application.yml file

```
customconfig:
    layout: foo
```

Is there a way for me to get this value in my file \src\main\templates\scaffolding\index.gsp by doing something like:

```
<meta name="layout" content="${grailsApplication.config.customconfig.layout}" />
```

I would like the code in my generated view to be:

```
<meta name="layout" content="foo" />
```

Everything I've tried so far give me an error when trying to generate my view:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: No such property: grails for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I am using Grails 3.0.11

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: In grails 3, scaffolding script is a code generation script that doesn't have access to grailsApplication as during this period application doesn't gets loaded.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia Thanks for the reply. I will seek other options then.

Comment: Check possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34648837/2166188